# Missing valid api key with Google Sheets API v4 for Laravel package

Tags: laravel-5, google-sheets

I am using [this](https://github.com/kawax/laravel-google-sheets) API to access a google spreadsheet content.

But i got this error while trying to access a spread

```
{\n
  "error": {\n
    "code": 403,\n
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",\n
    "errors": [\n
      {\n
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",\n
        "domain": "global",\n
        "reason": "forbidden"\n
      }\n
    ],\n
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"\n
  }\n
}


This is how i created the project
1) Create a new project.
2) Click Enable API. Search for and enable the Google Drive API.
3) Create credentials for a Web Server to access Application Data.
4) Name the service account and grant it a Project Role of Editor.
```